# Basic highcharts plugin, need to remove line between point

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I use basic type of highchart to draw graphic, but I do not want to connect the points. Just the point is enough. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use the same magic that i just used to fix your code. (post relevant code...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a scatter chart type:

```
chart: {
        type: 'scatter'
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-cursor-scatter/